# How to build a whitelist of domains we ignore SPF check for in Postfix

Tags: postfix, spf

My question would seem to be the opposite of [How to setup postfix to check SPF record only for domains that i want to check](https://serverfault.com/questions/726471/how-to-setup-postfix-to-check-spf-record-only-for-domains-that-i-want-to-check) -

How would I go about modifying my Postfix server so that it checks SPF for incoming emails by default, but allows me to retain a whitelist of domains that can bypass the check?

My main.conf file includes a stanza :

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031,
                permit_mynetworks, 
                permit_sasl_authenticated,
                reject_unauth_destination,
                check_policy_service unix:private/spfpolicy
```

(10031 is policyd, btw)

My master.conf file includes a stanza :

```
spfpolicy       unix    -       n       n       -       -       spawn
        user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/postfix-policyd-spf-perl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this method.

I have a list with white-listed and black-listed domains:

*/etc/postfix/sender_checks*

```
example.com REJECT Spam detected
example.org REJECT Spam detected
example.net OK
```

This file has to be hashed when it is changed.

```
postmap /etc/postfix/sender_checks
```

The hash map is referenced with `check_sender_access` in the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` directive:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  reject_invalid_hostname
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain
  reject_unauth_pipelining
  reject_non_fqdn_sender
  reject_unknown_sender_domain
  reject_non_fqdn_recipient
  permit_mynetworks
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  reject_unauth_destination
  check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_checks
  reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net,
  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
  reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
  reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org,
  reject_rbl_client dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net,
  check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf,
  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/custom_replies
```

You can move the `check_sender_access` check further to the front if you need to.